# After XP SP3 System Restore Point Used Reboot Stalls

Tags: windows-xp, reboot, system-restore

About 1.5 hours ago I set an XP SP3 box to reset to a system restore point.  This appeared to go as usual until the "Windows is shutting down" screen appeared.  THe machine has not continued the reboot process.

What is the recommended next step(s) and any precautions we can take to preserve the OS and files at this juncture?

Comment: If the HDD is flashing every now and then, and you really want it to work, leave it overnight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooted 12 hours later and found issue was that a virus had edited the registry and set HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT => .exe => (Default) key to something other than 'exefile'.

The result of this was that the system restore point exe could not fire as it should.

Setting the key value back to exefile allowed the system restore point to complete.